# Google Drive API v3: how to set canCopy capabilities on a file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-client

I want to limit the capabilities of a file in personal Google Drive.  When I use the API explorer [Google Drive v3 API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/) with the following request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "capabilities": {
  "canCopy": false
 },
 "name": "testfile"
}
```

I get the following response:

```
403


- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "fieldNotWritable",
    "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
 }
}
```

Which is the same response that I get when trying to update a file with:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FileIdHere?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "capabilities": {
  "canCopy": false
 }
}
```

It seems that there are no methods to accomplish this or has anyone a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you check [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)  you will notice that some fields are writeable while others are not.

The message you are seeing is because the field you are trying to set is not writeable this means you can not change it from the API

Comment: any idea on how to set then?

Comment: You can probably set it in the website.

Comment: hehe indeed that is possible, but I am looking via API way to do it and by using the API explorer I do not find a way...

Comment: That's because you can't not everything is possible through the API